# Reading from Text File writing to another File and Screen

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LBL 2
#define NUMROWS 24
#define NUMCOLS 80

int main ( void )

{

    FILE *fp = fopen( "/home/me/Desktop/screen.in", "r" );
    FILE *fo = fopen( "/home/me/Desktop/screen.out", "w+" );


    char x;
    int l;
    int r;
    char L[LBL][NUMCOLS];

        l = 0;

        while ( ( l < NUMROWS) && ( ( x = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF ) )

        {
            r = 0;

            while  ( ( r < NUMCOLS ) && ( x != '\n' ) )
            {
                L[l][r] = x;
                printf( "%c", x );
                fputc( x , fo );
                r++;
            }
                L[l][r] = x;
                printf( "%c",'\n' );
                fputc( x , fo );
                l++;
        }

fclose( fp );
fclose( fo );

}
```

---

### The following is an input file for testing:

```
                                 System Etc Etc                               
                         Next line etc etc                                

                identifier which will be replaced by a code fragment      
                  FFER_SIZE as an abbreviation for the token              

                   simple identifier which will be replaced by a          

                ill recognize and expand the macro BUFFER_SIZE. The       

               's body, expansion or replacement list. For example,       
                    ck the features they intend to implemen               
                   recognize and expand the macro BUFFER_SIZE.            

                 macro's body, expansion or replacement list.             

            then the C preprocessor will recognize and expand the macro   

             macro's body, expansion or replacement list. For example,    

              d object-like because it looks like a data object in        

          nd of the ‘#define’ line. You may continue the definition ont   
         njnfk;db; B;kdbw kb fkBNWKdbnW;KNWKNBKWBN
```

---

Essentially I want to read in any text file of 24 rows and 80 columns and 1.0 put each character into an array of characters and write an identical copy to a new File, including end of lines, all while presenting the input in exact same orientation to the computer screen.  he code compiles but does not produce output to either the screen nor output file.  I thought I had the correct syntax but it does not work.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int` (not a `char` that may not be able to store EOF)

Comment: Additionally to the previous comment: 1. You don't test if `fopen` succeeds. 2. Your algorithm is completely flawed, because in the inner `while` loop you don't read from the input file at all. 3. Your program can be simplified a lot by using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/).

Comment: Good news!  Unix already has a command that does this so you don't have to implement one.  It's called ***tee*** and you use it like `tee screen.out < screen.in`  -- it will read from stdin, write to stdout **and** write to the file named on the command line.  Lucky you!

Comment: Michael   Thank you I have made changes to fix the inner loop to read from the input file.

Comment: cdlane  Thank you for your input.  I am trying to save the intermediate state in an Array and then print to screen and file on an event which might occur intermittently.

Answer (score 2):

You basically have a bad implementation of a bad algorithm.  So let's rethink: the two dimensional array `L` isn't doing anything for you so let's toss it; let's use meaningful variable names; we don't need to open the output file "w+", just "w" will do fine; your inner `while` loop isn't doing the right thing as it's not taking on additional input, so let's replace it with an `if` statement and make what immediately follows, the `else` clause; your handling of newline on output is inconsistent; you've no error checking of the file opening as others have noted.

Let's rebuild your code addressing the above and tweaking the style a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUMROWS 24
#define NUMCOLS 80

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "appropriate error message");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r" );

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "appropriate error message");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w" );

    if (output == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "appropriate error message");
        return 1;
    }

    int c, row = 0, column = 0;

    while (row < NUMROWS && (c = fgetc(input)) != EOF)
    {
        if (column < NUMCOLS && c != '\n')
        {
            fputc(c, stdout);
            fputc(c, output);
        }
        else
        {
            fputc('\n', stdout);
            fputc('\n', output);
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Now you can do:

```
> ./a.out screen.in screen.out
```

The contents of the input (`screen.in`) will be output to both the screen (stdout) and the file `screen.out` but truncated to 24 rows and 80 columns.

Comment: Thank you for your help with the code.  As anyone can see I am not an accomplished coder.  This now works for the input and screen output.  This chunk of code will be a Function once finished and as such I will actually need the L array of characters.  The array would be resident in memory and be updated on a schedule.  Other operations would feed off of the array on a ongoing basis (control loop) 24/7.

Comment: cdlane  Thank you for the code modifications I have adopted them and they work fine. :)